# Using 'if (isset($_GET' to retrieve composite key instead of primary key

Tags: php

If I was to get a primary key then I would do this:

```
if (isset($_GET['item_id']))
```

But if the table had a composite key (2 attributes that act as a primary key), how would I do this? My 2 attributes acting as a composite key are item_id and size_id

Comment: `$_GET` has no relation to your database.  It's merely a method of getting input from the browser to the server. Once on the server, you would get the value from `$_GET` and use it in a query variable. For a composite key query, you might need two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access a row in your database with 2 attributes, then you need to be doing something like:

```
if (isset($_GET['item_id']) && isset($_GET('size_id')))
```

The other part can't magically appear unless you provide it in some other way.

Comment: Or just: `if (isset($_GET['item_id'], $_GET['size_id']))`